# Почему не работает запрос?

Tags: search, mysql

Запрос не выдает результата, хотя в таблице он точно есть. Сам запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks`
WHERE MATCH (`description`) AGAINST (?)
ORDER BY MATCH (`description`) AGAINST (?)
DESC
```

где `?` строка поиска.

Эмуляция на [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/562d41/4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил, установкой `IN BOOLEAN MODE`

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks`
WHERE MATCH (`description`) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH (`description`) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
DESC
```